# Azure Load test does not report data driven urls

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a simple load test that basically executes a single webtest on a constant load. That webtest is hooked to an xml file data source that contains urls to my entire site.

When I execute the load test from my local environment, the test summary page reports the individual urls in the "Top 5 slowest pages" i.e. "https://mysite.or/page" . But when I execute the same test from Azure (i.e. changed Test run location to VSTS in .testsettings), the links are reported as "https://{{Enviroment}}{{Sitemap.url.loc}}". This seems to be just a reporting issue and I can validate that azure is correctly invoking the urls from the data source. Why would the tests from Azure not report the url constructed from the datasource?

**Load Test Summary: Executed from Local**
[image: Local Test Summary]
**Same test executed on Azure**
[image: Azure Test Summary]

**Webtest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebTest Name="GenericSitemap" Id="02954e81-f3a7-4c9c-94f5-3a4304f88361" Owner="" Priority="2147483647" Enabled="True" CssProjectStructure="" CssIteration="" Timeout="0" WorkItemIds="" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010" Description="" CredentialUserName="" CredentialPassword="" PreAuthenticate="True" Proxy="default" StopOnError="False" RecordedResultFile="" ResultsLocale="">
  <Items>
    <Request Method="GET" Guid="01c37ffa-92db-42e8-9d25-a042dcd0123d" Version="1.1" Url="https://{{Enviroment}}{{Sitemap.url.loc}}" ThinkTime="0" Timeout="300" ParseDependentRequests="True" FollowRedirects="True" RecordResult="True" Cache="False" ResponseTimeGoal="0" Encoding="utf-8" ExpectedHttpStatusCode="0" ExpectedResponseUrl="https://{{Enviroment}}{{Sitemap.url.loc}}" ReportingName="" IgnoreHttpStatusCode="False" />
  </Items>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="Sitemap" Provider="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML" Connection="|DataDirectory|\..\Data\sitemap.xml">
      <Tables>
        <DataSourceTable Name="url" SelectColumns="SelectOnlyBoundColumns" AccessMethod="Random" />
      </Tables>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <ContextParameters>
    <ContextParameter Name="Enviroment" Value="mysite.net" />
  </ContextParameters>
</WebTest>
```

Comment: I have no idea on why it is happening as you report. For a possible workaround, you could create a `WebTestRequestPlugin` whose `PreRequest` method sets the `e.Request.ReportingName` property. You may need to build the name, or expand the context parameters, yourself. I think the finally reported name only has characters after the last `/`. (Apologies, unable to check or verify these ideas at present.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AdrianHHH. I got it working by creating a requestPlugin and setting it on the data driven requests.

Here's my plugin:

```
[DisplayName("Set Request Params")]
[Description("Fix request urls when run from Azure")]
public class SetRequestParams : WebTestRequestPlugin
{
    public override void PreRequest(object sender, PreRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Request.ReportingName = e.Request.Url;
    }
}
```